# Scale image inside a responsive container

Tags: html, css

So I'm developing a mobile friendly layout with squares and rectangles only. It has thumbnails with pictures and captions. To make that more visually dynamic I wanted to make a hover effect on the thumbnails.

The problem is, that the `img` container is a responsive object, and when it scales to make a zoom-in effect, it also scales it's container

Is it any way con scale the `img` only and not it's container?

This is the undesired effect I've got so far:

```css
.tile{
    position:  relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease; 
}
.tile:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}


.tile img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.tile:hover img { 
 transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <img src="http://p2.trrsf.com/image/fget/cf/600/600/images.terra.com/2013/10/16/2014-range-rover-evoque.jpg" />  
</div>
```

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your tile class.